# Space voyage movie, circa 1970, with a reverse sequence ending

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

I saw it when I was elementary school age, that's how I date it, but that's also why I'm unsure of the details, except some really weird ones.

- The space ship may be segmented, somewhat like a train.
- There's a scene where a young stowaway is discovered; he stands on legs that have no feet.
- The climax is some kind of catastrophe that makes people want to escape.
- During this catastrophe, a small group of people are in what seems to be a conference room. It has a wall-sized video screen. Someone "tunes in"  a view of a peaceful meadow or forest... then, somehow, the people are able to step into the video screen, and make their escape that way.
- The movie ends with a fast rewind of events.

I have searched and searched, but am not getting anywhere. What's the name of this movie?

Comment: If someone posts a correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Except for the first two bullet points this strikes me as a description of the ending of "the Time Travelers" (1964).

Basically the scientists try to tune their portal to get back to their own time from the post apocalyptic future the majority of the film takes place in. Specifically they are running from the mutant assault on the people (underground base) they found refuge with.

Youtube video of clips from throughout the film but includes ending scenes and the weird replay loop the movie ends with.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Travelers_(1964_film)

Quoting Wikipedia's plot summary ending…

> When the last one goes through, the screen flashes on briefly and shows the travelers walking in a clearing with trees and grass; the surface of the Earth habitable again. They begin to build a future there. The film then shows their past selves moving at normal speed again, repeating their actions at an ever accelerating rate to a resounding musical score; the sequence of events of the entire movie rapidly cycles, repeating with ever briefer and fewer clips, leaving the viewer in a time-loop until it abruptly ends (without further explanation) with a shot of the Andromeda Galaxy.

Comment: *“Youtube video of clips from throughout the film but includes ending scenes”* It a word missing?

Comment: I think one of the mutants who infiltrates the sanxtuary might be the mutant @mmraff is recalling

Comment: Fantastic! This is most likely what I saw, because that wall portal and the glade they escape into matches my memory. And then there's the guy standing on legs with no feet at 2:42, and his face is so familiar.  I guess my memory of a segmented spaceship leaked in from some other movie.